# 英文の意味を正しく理解できません

Tags: php, 英語, oss, symfony

OSSにドキュメントの修正でプルリクを送ったところ拒否されましたが、その返信の内容がわかりませんでした。以下URLとその返信内容です。

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/35730

**返信内容:**

> We never add phpdocs that do not add anything that is not already part of the method signature.

**Google翻訳:**

> メソッドシグネチャの一部ではないものを追加しないphpdocsは追加しません

自分は何がいけなかったのでしょうか。是非ご教示願えればと思います。

Comment: 三重否定になっているので、日本語にされたってわかりにくいですが、少し表現を変えると「シグニチャーに既に含まれている情報しか追加して無いようなphpdocsは追加しないよ」って、ことです。「シグニチャー(メソッド名や引数名、引数型)でわかるような情報をheader docに記述しちゃいけない」と言うheader docの原則(日本のプロジェクトだと守られていないことが多いですが)を守れ、と言う趣旨でしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、理解しました。

Comment: 参考までに、例えば `set()` method の PHPDoc ですが、[この commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/b64fdb7c0a362a72c07f0e8e0317bdc254e437c7#diff-1df5b32be44d0f592ec285c6bbf386bb) で削除されています。Comit log には `[DI] deprecate support for non-object services` という文言があって、DI 関連(`Container.php`, `ContainerBuilder.php`, `ContainerInterface.php`)内の `set()` method の PHPDoc が削除されています。

Answer (score 3):

三重否定になっているので、日本語にされたってわかりにくいですが、少し表現を変えると「シグニチャーに既に含まれている情報しか追加して無いようなphpdocsは追加しないよ」って、ことです。

「シグニチャー(メソッド名や引数名、引数型)でわかるような情報をheader docに記述しちゃいけない」と言うheader docの原則(日本のプロジェクトだと守られていないことが多いですが)を守れ、と言う趣旨でしょう。

---

<sup>この投稿は @OOPer さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63078/#comment69073_63078)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>